# snakemake: archive just conda envs as yaml

Tags: conda, snakemake

After each snakemake pipeline run, I'd like to save a yaml export of each conda env (via `onsuccess:`). One can create a tarball of the entire pipeline, but I just want to export the conda envs as yaml files, especially given how long it can take to create a tarball of everything. I have not found a good way of doing this, especially in regards to associating the conda env name in the workflow with the md5 used in `.snakemake/conda/`.

Comment: why not wrapping the call to snakemake and exporting the env from the wrapper? Snakemake returns error code 0 if it runs successfully. You can check for that and trigger your export then.